# Fill the form UP or Fill the form IN

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs

In school, for exams we FILL UP forms.

But I have seen people saying "FILL IN the form."

Fill the form in OR fill  the form up, which is correct. Please explain.

Answer (score 5):

"Filling up" a form was common in British English before about 1920. Still common in Indian English, but very obsolete elsewhere. British "fill in" and American "fill out" are common these days.

British telegraph form (1890)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Fill *up*" a form is not really idiomatic, or at least not the most idiomatic phrasal verb for that context.  You *fill up* some kind of container, and you *fill in* something incomplete, such as a form.

Examples:

> Go to the well and **fill up** these buckets with water
>
> Could you please **fill in** the missing information on this spreadsheet before we send it to the client?

It is possible to ask someone to "fill up" a form in a joking or metaphorical way, as if it was like a bucket of water, if you wanted to add that nuance.

Comment: I would look at someone quizzically if they asked me to fill-up a form.